# Converting C# Razor view syntax for checkboxlist into VB.Net

Tags: html-helper, c#-to-vb.net

Here is the HTML code for "CheckBoxListFor" which I copied from "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-a-missing-MVC-extension" Could you please help me out in converting this C# code into VB.Net?

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedCities.CityIDs, 
                      model => model.AvailableCities, 
                      entity => entity.Id, 
                      entity => entity.Name, 
                      model => model.SelectedCities)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(Function(model) model.PostedCities.CityIDs, _
                      Function(model) model.AvailableCities, _
                      Function(entity) entity.Id, _
                      Function(entity) entity.Name, _
                      Function(entity) If(Model.SelectedCities Is Nothing, False, Model.SelectedCities.Contains(entity.Id)),
htmlListInfo, Function(htmlAttribute) New With {.class = "chkBoxList"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(Function(model) model.PostedCities.CityIDs, _
                      Function(model) model.AvailableCities, _
                      Function(entity) entity.Id, _
                      Function(entity) entity.Name, _
                      Function(model) model.SelectedCities)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is a small problem with above solution. It raises exception if model.SelectedCities is nothing/null. But I have already found the solution which is best suitable for my requirement. I am going to post my answer now as I just saw your reply.